Get Sessions variables/connection to stay connected for 24 hours instead of 24 minutes in PHP
I am working on a new website using PHP/MariaDB.
I implanted facebook login with this tutorial (https://codeshack.io/implement-facebook-login-php/) and it works great.  I am now fully approved on facebook side and my connections works well and I added a MariaDB database table to manage connection and futur personnalisation for users.
My problem is that my session only stays on for 24 minutes which is the default in php.
I have changed the session.gc_maxlifetime parameter both in my local and main php.ini file to 86400 (which is the desired 24h in seconds).  After this I was still limited for no known reason to the default 24 min value so I added this to the top of my php file :
 ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 86400);
After this I was able to get the desired value from :
console.log('<?php echo ini_get("session.gc_maxlifetime"); ?>'); 
// returns 86400;
After this it was still disconnecting so I added :
session_set_cookie_params(0);
Even with 0 or 86400 it still disconnect earlier.
I then added this that was supposed to help :
if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] > 60000)) {
    // last request was more than 30 minutes ago
    session_unset();     // unset $_SESSION variable for the run-time 
    session_destroy();   // destroy session data in storage
}
$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time(); // update last activity time stamp

if (!isset($_SESSION['CREATED'])) {
    $_SESSION['CREATED'] = time();
} else if (time() - $_SESSION['CREATED'] > 30000) {
    // session started more than 30 minutes ago
    session_regenerate_id(true);    // change session ID for the current session and 
    invalidate old session ID
    $_SESSION['CREATED'] = time();  // update creation time
}

I am now looking forward to get any way to just let my users stay connected more then 24 minutes!!  The connection is used to personnalize web site options so no big security issue here.
Thanks for your help magnificent community!!!
Here is my oAuth file :
<?php 
ini_set('session.save_path',realpath(dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) . '../../sessions'));

// server should keep session data for AT LEAST 1 hour
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 86400);

// each client should remember their session id for EXACTLY 1 hour
session_set_cookie_params(0);

session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] > 60000)) {
    // last request was more than 30 minutes ago
    session_unset();     // unset $_SESSION variable for the run-time 
    session_destroy();   // destroy session data in storage
}
$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time(); // update last activity time stamp

if (!isset($_SESSION['CREATED'])) {
$_SESSION['CREATED'] = time();
} else if (time() - $_SESSION['CREATED'] > 30000) {
    // session started more than 30 minutes ago
    session_regenerate_id(true);    // change session ID for the current session and invalidate old session ID
    $_SESSION['CREATED'] = time();  // update creation time
}


include '../scripts/php_connect.php';


// Update the following variables
$facebook_oauth_app_id = 'XXXXXXXX';
$facebook_oauth_app_secret = 'XXXXXXXX';
// Must be the direct URL to the facebook-oauth.php file
$facebook_oauth_redirect_uri = 'XXXXXXXX';
$facebook_oauth_version = 'v19.0';

// If the captured code param exists and is valid
if (isset($_GET['code']) && !empty($_GET['code'])) {
    // Execute cURL request to retrieve the access token
    
    $params = [
        'client_id' => $facebook_oauth_app_id,
        'client_secret' => $facebook_oauth_app_secret,
        'redirect_uri' => $facebook_oauth_redirect_uri,
        'code' => $_GET['code']
    ];
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($params));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $response = json_decode($response, true);

    
} else {
    // Define params and redirect to Facebook OAuth page
    $params = [
        'client_id' => $facebook_oauth_app_id,
        'redirect_uri' => $facebook_oauth_redirect_uri,
        'response_type' => 'code',
        'scope' => 'email'
    ];
    header('Location: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?' . http_build_query($params));
    exit;
}

if (isset($response['access_token']) && !empty($response['access_token'])) {
    // Execute cURL request to retrieve the user info associated with the Facebook account
    // Execute cURL request to retrieve the user info associated with the Facebook account
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://graph.facebook.com/' . $facebook_oauth_version . '/me?fields=name,email,picture');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Authorization: Bearer ' . $response['access_token']]);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $profile = json_decode($response, true);
    
    
        // Make sure the profile data exists
    if (isset($profile['email'])) {
        
        // Store a string into the variable which
        // need to be Encrypted
        $simple_string = $profile['email'];

        // Store the cipher method
        $ciphering = "AES-128-CTR";

        // Use OpenSSl Encryption method
        $iv_length = openssl_cipher_iv_length($ciphering);
        $options = 0;

        // Non-NULL Initialization Vector for encryption
        $encryption_iv = 'XXXXXX';

        // Store the encryption key
        $encryption_key = "XXXXXXXX";

        // Use openssl_encrypt() function to encrypt the data
        $encryption = openssl_encrypt($simple_string, $ciphering,
                    $encryption_key, $options, $encryption_iv);

        // Check if the account exists in the database
        $stmt = $dbPDO->prepare("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email = ?");
        $stmt->execute([ $encryption ]);
        $account = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        // If the account does not exist in the database, insert the account into the database
        if (!$account) {
            $stmt = $dbPDO->prepare("INSERT INTO XXXXXX (email, name, picture, registered, method) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
            $stmt->execute([ $encryption, $profile['name'], $profile['picture']['data']['url'], date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), 'facebook' ]);
            $id = $dbPDO->lastInsertId();
        } else {
            $id = $account['ID'];
        }
        // Authenticate the account
        session_regenerate_id();
        $_SESSION['facebook_loggedin'] = TRUE;
        $_SESSION['facebook_id'] = $id;
        // Redirect to profile page
        //echo $_SESSION['facebook_loggedin'] . $_SESSION['facebook_id'];
        header('Location: profile.php');
        exit;
    } else {
        //echo "test";
        exit('Could not retrieve profile information! Please try again later!');
    }
} else {
    exit('Invalid access token! Please try again later!');
}

?>

AND here is my sample header page :
<?php
if ( !isset( $_SESSION ) ) {
    ini_set( 'session.save_path', realpath( dirname( $_SERVER[ 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' ] ) . '../../sessions' ) );
    
    // server should keep session data for AT LEAST 1 hour
    ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 86400);

    
    session_set_cookie_params(0);
    
    session_start();  
}
include 'scripts/php_connect.php';

$permissions = [];

if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] > 30000)) {
    // last request was more than 30 minutes ago
    session_unset();     // unset $_SESSION variable for the run-time 
    session_destroy();   // destroy session data in storage
}
$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time(); // update last activity time stamp

if (!isset($_SESSION['CREATED'])) {
$_SESSION['CREATED'] = time();
} else if (time() - $_SESSION['CREATED'] > 30000) {
    // session started more than 30 minutes ago
    session_regenerate_id(true);    // change session ID for the current session and invalidate old session ID
    $_SESSION['CREATED'] = time();  // update creation time
}
    

if ( isset( $_SESSION[ 'facebook_loggedin' ] ) ) {

    // Get the account from the database
    $stmt = $dbPDO->prepare('SELECT * FROM XXXXXX WHERE ID = ?');
    $stmt->execute([ $_SESSION['facebook_id'] ]);
    $account = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    // Retrieve session variables
    $facebook_loggedin = $_SESSION['facebook_loggedin'];
    

    // Define the data to encrypt
    $data = $account['email'];

    // Define the secret key
    $key = "XXXXXXXX";

    // Define the encryption method
    $method = "XXXXXX";

    // Generate a random initialization vector (IV)
    $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length($method));

    // Decode the encrypted data
    $encrypted = base64_decode($data);

    // Extract the IV and the encrypted data
    $iv = substr($encrypted, 0, openssl_cipher_iv_length($method));
    $encrypted = substr($encrypted, openssl_cipher_iv_length($method));

    // Decrypt the data
    $decrypted = openssl_decrypt($encrypted, $method, $key, 0, $iv);

    
    $user_email = $decrypted;
    $user_name = $account['name'];
    $facebook_picture = $account['picture'];
    $user_id = $account['ID'];

?>

Here is the server configs :
cPanel Version  110.0 (build 24)
Apache Version  2.4.58
MySQL Version   10.6.17-MariaDB-cll-lve-log
Architecture    x86_64
Operating System    linux
Perl Version    5.16.3
Kernel Version  4.18.0-372.16.1.lve.el7h.x86_64

Did you restart the webserver service after changing that parameter?

I will try to do it.  Ca it be done throught cpanel?

I am not sure. Maybe you need ask your hoster if you have no terminal access.

ini_set only changes the configuration at runtime - so there is little point in a server restart here. Are you sure you are making these settings every single time you pick up the session? (This should really go into an extra file that you can then include in all the other pages, rather than be repeated in multiple locations.)

The directory where the session files are stored on the server - are you sharing that with anyone, perhaps? Other scripts on your own site, that might use different session settings? Other user accounts on the same server even perhaps?

@CBroe Yes it is in my header file that is called in every page.  It is only repeated in the oAuth file since it has no graphical design.

@CBroe no I created the folder only for this purpose.

I ended out creating a cookie with a 24h duration with the encoded facebook_id and It worked.
<?php 
ini_set('session.save_path',realpath(dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) . '../../sessions'));

// server should keep session data for AT LEAST 1 hour
//ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 86400);

// each client should remember their session id for EXACTLY 1 hour
session_set_cookie_params(86400);

session_start();

include '../scripts/php_connect.php';

// Update the following variables
$facebook_oauth_app_id = 'XXXXXXXXXXX';
$facebook_oauth_app_secret = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
// Must be the direct URL to the facebook-oauth.php file
$facebook_oauth_redirect_uri = 'https://domain.name/facebook-oauth.php';
$facebook_oauth_version = 'v19.0';

// If the captured code param exists and is valid
if (isset($_GET['code']) && !empty($_GET['code'])) {
    // Execute cURL request to retrieve the access token
    
    $params = [
        'client_id' => $facebook_oauth_app_id,
        'client_secret' => $facebook_oauth_app_secret,
        'redirect_uri' => $facebook_oauth_redirect_uri,
        'code' => $_GET['code']
    ];
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($params));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $response = json_decode($response, true);

    
} else {
    // Define params and redirect to Facebook OAuth page
    $params = [
        'client_id' => $facebook_oauth_app_id,
        'redirect_uri' => $facebook_oauth_redirect_uri,
        'response_type' => 'code',
        'scope' => 'email'
    ];
    header('Location: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?' . http_build_query($params));
    exit;
}

if (isset($response['access_token']) && !empty($response['access_token'])) {
    // Execute cURL request to retrieve the user info associated with the Facebook account
    // Execute cURL request to retrieve the user info associated with the Facebook account
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://graph.facebook.com/' . $facebook_oauth_version . '/me?fields=name,email,picture');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Authorization: Bearer ' . $response['access_token']]);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $profile = json_decode($response, true);
    
    
        // Make sure the profile data exists
    if (isset($profile['email'])) {
        
        // Store a string into the variable which
        // need to be Encrypted
        $simple_string = $profile['email'];

        // Store the cipher method
        $ciphering = "AES-128-CTR";

        // Use OpenSSl Encryption method
        $iv_length = openssl_cipher_iv_length($ciphering);
        $options = 0;

        // Non-NULL Initialization Vector for encryption
        $encryption_iv = 'XXXXXXXXXXX';

        // Store the encryption key
        $encryption_key = "XXXXXXXXXXX";

        // Use openssl_encrypt() function to encrypt the data
        $encryption = openssl_encrypt($simple_string, $ciphering,
                    $encryption_key, $options, $encryption_iv);

        // Check if the account exists in the database
        $stmt = $dbPDO->prepare("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email = ?");
        $stmt->execute([ $encryption ]);
        $account = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        // If the account does not exist in the database, insert the account into the database
        if (!$account) {
            $stmt = $dbPDO->prepare("INSERT INTO accounts (email, name, picture, registered, method) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
            $stmt->execute([ $encryption, $profile['name'], $profile['picture']['data']['url'], date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), 'facebook' ]);
            $id = $dbPDO->lastInsertId();
        } else {
            $id = $account['ID'];
        }
        
        // Authenticate the account
        session_regenerate_id();
        $_SESSION['facebook_loggedin'] = TRUE;
        $_SESSION['facebook_id'] = $id;
        
        setcookie("facebook_loggedin", "TRUE", time() + (86400 * 1), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
        setcookie("facebook_id", openssl_encrypt($id, $ciphering,
                    $encryption_key, $options, $encryption_iv), time() + (86400 * 1), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day

        // Redirect to profile page
        //echo $_SESSION['facebook_loggedin'] . $_SESSION['facebook_id'];
        header('Location: profile.php');
        exit;
    } else {
        //echo "test";
        exit('Could not retrieve profile information! Please try again later!');
    }
} else {
    exit('Invalid access token! Please try again later!');
}

?>

And the profile file :
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    ini_set('session.save_path',realpath(dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) . '../../sessions'));

    // server should keep session data for AT LEAST 1 hour
    //ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 86400);

    // each client should remember their session id for EXACTLY 1 hour
    session_set_cookie_params(86400);
    
    session_start();    
}
/*
if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] > 60000)) {
    // last request was more than 30 minutes ago
    session_unset();     // unset $_SESSION variable for the run-time 
    session_destroy();   // destroy session data in storage
}
$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time(); // update last activity time stamp

if (!isset($_SESSION['CREATED'])) {
$_SESSION['CREATED'] = time();
} else if (time() - $_SESSION['CREATED'] > 30000) {
    // session started more than 30 minutes ago
    session_regenerate_id(true);    // change session ID for the current session and invalidate old session ID
    $_SESSION['CREATED'] = time();  // update creation time
}

*/


// Check if the user is logged in, if not then redirect to login page
if (!isset($_SESSION['facebook_loggedin']) && !isset($_COOKIE["facebook_loggedin"])) {
    header('Location: login.php');
    exit;
} else {
    
    // Store the cipher method
    $ciphering = "AES-128-CTR";

    // Use OpenSSl Encryption method
    $iv_length = openssl_cipher_iv_length($ciphering);
    $options = 0;
    
    // Non-NULL Initialization Vector for decryption
    $decryption_iv = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

    // Store the decryption key
    $decryption_key = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    
    if (isset($_SESSION['facebook_id'])) {
        $facebook_id = ($_SESSION['facebook_id'] != "" ?  $_SESSION['facebook_id'] : "");
    } else {
        $facebook_id = ($_COOKIE["facebook_id"] != "" ? openssl_decrypt ($_COOKIE["facebook_id"], $ciphering, $decryption_key, $options, $decryption_iv) : "");
    }
    
    // Database connection variables
    include '../scripts/php_connect.php';

    // Get the account from the database
    $stmt = $dbPDO->prepare('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE ID = ?');
    $stmt->execute([ $facebook_id ]);
    $account = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    
    
    // Retrieve session variables
    $facebook_loggedin = (isset($_SESSION['facebook_loggedin']) && $_SESSION['facebook_loggedin'] != "" ? $_SESSION['facebook_loggedin'] : $_COOKIE["facebook_loggedin"]);


    // Use openssl_decrypt() function to decrypt the data
    $decryption=openssl_decrypt ($account['email'], $ciphering, $decryption_key, $options, $decryption_iv);

    
    $user_email = $decryption;
    $user_name = $account['name'];
    $facebook_picture = $account['picture'];
    $user_id = $account['ID'];

    $sql = "SELECT Permission, Description FROM accounts_permissions WHERE ID = :userID ORDER BY Description ASC";

    $stmt = $dbPDO->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':userID', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
    $stmt->closeCursor();
    if ($result) {
        foreach($result as $permission) {
            $permissions[$permission["Permission"]] = $permission["Description"];
        }
    } else {
        $permissions[1] = 'Accès générale';
    }
}




?>

If this can help someone!
